# how to create class Searchp extends StatelessWidget implements SearchDelegate <an_object> from scratch

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am a newbie at flutter and now I am trying to implement a search delegate bar according to what I need to finish a restaurant app. The default search delegate from [Flutter's Search Support (The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI&t=1414s) is not flexible enough because my "shopping cart" is a Scrollable BottomSheet and when I tap on search icon my search delegate take the lead I added my cart on the page expecting the scrollabe Bottomsheet take the entire screen when scrolling that but the sheet can't scroll over the search delegate appBar. Stucked on this since 4 days, I thinking to implement the hole search delegate to access the build(BuildContext context) to put a Stack over there but I don't how to implement it from scratch (only know the flutter search from [Flutter's Search Support (The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI&t=1414s)). If you have other way to solve my issue thanks. These are images:
search bar and the sheet at its initial position   [initial position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Puh.jpg)

search stucked [appbar search delegate don't allow the sheet to sroll over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXQAP.jpg)

what I need [the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QPFk.jpg)

this is the code I have rigth now for the search delagate :

```
    @override
    List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement buildActions
      return [
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed:(){
              query = "";
            }
        )
      ];
    }

    @override
    Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement buildLeading
      return IconButton(icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon:AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
          onPressed:(){
            close(context,null);
          }
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement buildResults
      final suggestionList =query.isEmpty?food_recent:data.where((p)=> p.toString().contains(query)).toList();

      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return  Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // SizedBox(height: 8),
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 0.8,
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 1,
                        child:ListView.builder(
                          //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, top: 128),
                          //controller: scrollController,
                          itemCount: suggestionList?.length ?? 0, //20,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            //Event event = events[index % 3];
                            Produit event = suggestionList[index];
                            return MyEventItemProduct(
                              event: event,
                              percentageCompleted:0.15,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    //Tabs(),
                    //SizedBox(height: 8),
                    //SlidingCardsView(),
                  ],
                ),
                ScrollableExhibitionSheet(),//use this or ScrollableExhibitionSheet
              ],
            );
          });
    }

        @override
        Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
          // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
          //new Text(suggestionList[index]["colis"]["libelle_coli"]),
          final suggestionList =query.isEmpty?food_recent:data.where((p)=> p.toString().contains(query)).toList();

          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return  Stack(
                  overflow: Overflow.clip,
                  children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // SizedBox(height: 8),
                          AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 0.8,
                              child: Opacity(
                                opacity: 1,
                                child:ListView.builder(
                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, top: 128),
                                  //controller: scrollController,
                                  itemCount: suggestionList?.length ?? 0, //20,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    //Event event = events[index % 3];
                                    Produit event = suggestionList[index];
                                    return MyEventItemProduct(
                                      event: event,
                                      percentageCompleted:0.15,
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                          )
                          //Tabs(),
                          //SizedBox(height: 8),
                          //SlidingCardsView(),
                        ],
                      ),

                     ScrollableExhibitionSheet(),//use this or ScrollableExhibitionSheet
                  ],
                );
              });
        }
```

and rigth because I don't know how to solve my problem I decide to implement it from srcatch to have the build method widget. this is what I am trying to do but I don't know how to implement the 10 other methods asked to made it work like the default appbar.

```
    class Searchp extends StatelessWidget implements SearchDelegate <Produit>{
      @override
      String query;

      @override
      ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement appBarTheme
        return null;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return null;
      }

      @override
      List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildActions


        return null;
      }

      @override
      Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildLeading

        return null;
      }

      @override
      Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildResults
        return null;
      }

      @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
        return null;
      }

      @override
      void close(BuildContext context, Produit result) {
        // TODO: implement close
      }

      @override
      // TODO: implement keyboardType
      TextInputType get keyboardType => null;

      @override
      // TODO: implement searchFieldLabel
      String get searchFieldLabel => null;

      @override
      void showResults(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement showResults
      }

      @override
      void showSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement showSuggestions
      }

      @override
      // TODO: implement textInputAction
      TextInputAction get textInputAction => null;

      @override
      // TODO: implement transitionAnimation
      Animation<double> get transitionAnimation => null;

    }
```

Comment: trying to understand in detail  how search delegate work by accessing de search.dart from src.material package. If someone knows another option or a code sample to achieve what I need, thanks to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally extends from StatelessWidget was not needed.
override the _SearchPageState class from [src/material/search.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search.dart)  solved my problem.